# REGEXP_EXTRACT Data Studio

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I have those type of strings in Data Studio:

```
Car;House;I have a car in my house
Mobile;Phone;She has a mobile phone
```

And I would like to get the last sentences: "I have a car in my house" , "She has a mobile phone". I am trying with extract the last sentence up ; but I can't get it with REGEXP_EXTRACT or REGEXP_MATCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REGEXP_EXTRACT` with a capture group should work here.  We can select semicolon followed by any non semicolon content, which should coincide only with the final sentence.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(String, ';([^;]+)$')
```

### Demo

The demo link above is just a pure regex demo, but it shows the capture group selecting the last sentence in the input.